# How to wait for multiple ajax requests, when the list grows as requests come in?

Tags: jquery

I know about "$.when.apply($, list)", but that only works when you have a set list. In my case, I'm essentially getting a tree of URLs over ajax, starting from a root URL that will point to 0 or more other URLs to get, which can each also point to 0 more other URLs, etc.

For example, suppose I get "URL1", which returns ["URL2", "URL3"], which means I also want those URLs, and so on. My first AJAX call to URL1 will complete *before* I can start my ajax calls to URL2 and URL3. Writing a function to retrieve the whole tree and store the data is easy enough, but what is a good way to trigger some action when *all* these AJAX calls are done?

Comment: Couldn't you just nest the ajax calls in the callback function of each call? Then only after the last call returns, it will go through the whole stack and return for each request's callback function. A kind of recursion-esque approach.

Comment: Say I do "$.ajax(url: url1, success: callbackFunc)". I can make callbackFunc do the ajax request to url2 and url3, but the callbackFunc will complete before those new ajax requests have finished. So I can use this to make all the ajax calls down the tree of URLs, but I still don't know how to know when all of them are done.

I could make synchronous ajax calls, but my impression is that'd be a bad idea, especially since I could end up needing to make a lot of calls and don't want to freeze my browser during that time.